# Returning a column from a linked table in LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

My problem is that I am trying to return a simple query that contains an object Story.  The Story object has a UserId in the table which links to aspnet_users' UserId column.  I have created a partial class for Story that adds the UserName property since it does not exist in the table itself.

The following query gets all stories; however, a pagination helper takes the query and returns only what's necessary once this is passed back to the controller.

```
     public IQueryable<Story> FindAllStories(){
        var stories = (from s in db.Stories
                       orderby s.DateEntered descending
                       select new Story
                       {     
                          Title = s.Title,
                          StoryContent = s.StoryContent,
                          DateEntered =  s.DateEntered,
                          DateUpdated =  s.DateUpdated,
                          UserName = s.aspnet_User.UserName
                        }
                        );

        return stories;
    }
```

When the helper does a .count() on the source it bombs with the following exception:

"Explicit construction of entity type 'MyWebsite.Models.Story' in query is not allowed."

Any ideas?  It's not a problem with the helper because I had this working when I simply had the UserName inside the Story table.  And on a side note - any book recommendations for getting up to speed on LINQ to SQL?  It's really kicking my butt.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is precisely what it tells you: you're not allowed to use `new Story` as the result of your query. Use an anonymous type instead (by omitting `Story` after `new`). If you still want `Story`, you can remap it later in LINQ to Objects:

```
    var stories =  from s in db.Stories
                   orderby s.DateEntered descending
                   select new
                   {     
                      Title = s.Title,
                      StoryContent = s.StoryContent,
                      DateEntered =  s.DateEntered,
                      DateUpdated =  s.DateUpdated,
                      UserName = s.aspnet_User.UserName
                    };

     stories = from s in stories.AsEnumerable() // L2O
               select new Story
               {
                   Title = s.Title,
                   StoryContent = s.StoryContent,
                   ...
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to return an IQueryable from your method and still need the Username of the user you can use DataContext.LoadOptions to eagerload your aspnet_user objects.

[See this example.](http://www.lowendahl.net/showShout.aspx?id=190)